# Detecting closed socket connection C#

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

How do you correctly detect that a connection has been closed by the client? I have tried a send test.

```
byte[] tmp = new byte[1];
bool blockingState = true;

if (_socket != null)
{
     blockingState = _socket.Blocking;
     _socket.Blocking = false;
     _socket.Send(tmp, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to poll  connection every time to see if connection is still active. This is code I used:**

```
bool SocketConnected(Socket s)
    {
        bool part1 = s.Poll(1000, SelectMode.SelectRead);
        bool part2 = (s.Available == 0);
        if (part1 && part2)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

**It works like this:**

s.Poll returns true if

- connection is closed, reset, terminated or pending (meaning no active
  connection)
- connection is active and there is data available for    reading

s.Available returns number of bytes available for reading

**if both are true:
there is no data available to read so connection is not active**